# Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API lookback longer than 30 days

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I got my Multi-Channel Funnels Report working with the API but it seems to only show a lookback window of 30 days by default.

Is there a way to get it to show 90 days like the web interface does?

I ran a report using `mcf:timeLagInDaysHistogram` and it showed `totalConversions` from 0-29 which I assume was the same as 1-30 lookback window in the web interface. Is that correct.

I tried using that as a filter by putting in `mcf:timeLagInDaysHistogram<=90` but AdWords Scrips error out on any thing in filters other than `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the lookback window cannot be adjusted. Per the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfDevGuide) -

> Note: The Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API uses a non-adjustable 30-day lookback window.